# Showing that an indefinite integral of a function with a jump discontinuity is not differentiable at the jump discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying to help this person with his question.

[Integrable but not differentiable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245984/integrable-but-not-differentiable-function/1246399#1246399)

Showing continuity was relatively easy, but I'm having trouble with showing that the function is not differentiable at $c$.

I tried using the hint and using one-sided derivatives, but all I got was that $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x\neq c$, and all I managed to show from that was that $\lim_\limits{x \to c} F'(x)$ does not exist. But all that showed was that the derivative of $F$ wasn't continuous at $c$, not that $F$ wasn't differentiable at $c$.

So I tried going down to Riemann sums. But I got stuck when showing that the last bit was a contradiction, since the absolute value of an integral is at most the integral of the absolute value of the integrand, not the other way round. I was wondering if it's salvageable, or if there are other errors I didn't see. Thanks!

Comment: Try showing that one-sided derivatives of F exist, but are not equal

Comment: @I'm having trouble with that, I had an edit before that showed that if $f$ is right-continuous at $c$, then $F$ is right differentiable at $c$ and the the derivative from the right is $\lim_{x\to c^+} f(x)$. But then I ran into trouble with the details when showing that $F$ must have unequal left and right derivatives.

Comment: What trouble? The left derivative has to be $\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x).$ By definition of a jump discontinuity, this is not equal to the limit from the right.

Comment: @zhw. How do I prove that? I get that the left derivative of $F$ at $c$ is:

$$\lim_\limits{x\to c^-} \frac{F(x)-F(c)}{x-c} =\lim_\limits{x\to c^-} \frac{\int_c^x f(t) dt}{x-c}  $$ but how is the that equal to $$\lim_\limits{x\to c^-} f(x)$$?

Comment: Define $g = f$ on $[a,c), g(c) = \lim_{x\to c^-}f(x).$ Then $g$ is continuous on $[a,c].$ Note $F(x)-F(c) = \int_c^x g.$ Because $g$ is continuous, you know the left derivative of $F$ at $c$ is $g(c).$

Comment: Thank you! I can finally finish that question.